# How to apply CSS transition on hide?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap `navbar` that on collapse displays the items outside of it. When collapsing I have a `div` that works as an overlay that covers the whole page, so the `navbar` menu does not stay on top of any content of the page. The problem happens when I hide the menu: the `div` disappears immediately and during the hiding transition of the menu it stays on top of the page's content.

I want to keep the menu transition, so how can I apply a transition to the `div` when it is hiding? I've tried a lot of approaches but all of them only apply the transition when the `div` shows and not when it hides.

Check this demo, please: https://codesandbox.io/s/d31eo

React (demo):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { name: "Test1" },
        { name: "Test2" },
        { name: "Test3" },
        { name: "Test4" }
      ]
    });
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar
          className={`nav ${this.state.open ? "open" : ""}`}
          expand="lg"
          sticky="top"
        >
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbar-menu" onClick={this.onClick} />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-menu">
              <Nav className="ml-auto">
                {this.state.data.map((category) => (
                  <Nav.Link href="#" key={`category-${category.name}`}>
                    <span className="link">{category.name}</span>
                  </Nav.Link>
                ))}
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
        <div className={`overlay ${this.state.open ? "open" : ""}`} />
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MXxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bmF0dXJhbHx8MHx8fA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS (demo):

```
.nav {
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}

.link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3e433e;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
}

@media (max-width: 1170px) {
  .collapsing {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
  }

  .collapse.show {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100%;
    top: 75px;
  }

  .overlay.open {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 55px; /* navbar min-heigth */
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the first demo on the bootstrap page different from your desired output? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Yes! I want to show the collapsible content outside the navbar. You can check the demo to see what I'm talking about :)

Comment: Okay! I guess you could literally copy the demo code from above

Comment: Not sure the question is clear if the answer didn't work. Could you try to summarize it slightly more succinctly? Why are the navbar items displayed outside? Why is there a div overlay? Can you give a simple non-technical explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know how to be more succint, sincerely. I just want to fix the CSS transition. Succint as that. The navbar items are displayed outside because is a design pre-requisite. The div overlay was just an idea of mine, I imagine that should've a way to achive what I want without it. Simplest explanation I can think: add a transition so the navbar items doesn't overlap the page's content when I toggle the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below link code? Hope it will work for you. We have moved all declarations of `.overlay.open` to `.overlay` and added ***transition*** to `.overlay`(Default State), we don't need to add ***transition*** in `.overlay.open`.

For smooth transition we have added transition in height and opacity in Default State

*`transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out, height 0.4s ease-in-out`*.

**1. In Default state** - `.overlay`:

`height` set to '0px' and `opacity` set to '0'.

**2. In Open state** - `.overlay.open`:

`height` set to '100%' and `opacity` set to '1'.

Please refer to this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-microservice-6d4c6

Comment: Perfect answer! I'm going to accept yours because, in my opinion, it was the one with the best transition. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1:

Move the styles of the overlay to its base css definition. leave in the `.open` only the css which should change on open. In our case we will change the height, so add `height:0` to base `.ovelay` css and `height:100%` to `.overlay.open`

#### Step 2:

Add a css transition (e.g. `transition: height .5s ease`) to the base css, and set `tansition: none` to `.overlay.open`. this way the transition will apply only when its not have `.open` class. So it wll openinstantly, and close animated.

Hopefully this was the desired output:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-drake-dbtce?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: Fantastic answer and explanation! I definitely learned something from you. Thanks for it!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the overlapping div for cover full body. We can manage it by the CSS property.

Use the following code for solving your problem.

React code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./styles.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { name: "Test1" },
        { name: "Test2" },
        { name: "Test3" },
        { name: "Test4" }
      ]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar
          className={`nav ${this.state.open ? "open" : ""}`}
          expand="lg"
          sticky="top"
        >
          <Container>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbar-menu" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-menu">
              <Nav className="ml-auto">
                {this.state.data.map((category) => (
                  <Nav.Link href="#" key={`category-${category.name}`}>
                    <span className="link">{category.name}</span>
                  </Nav.Link>
                ))}
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MXxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bmF0dXJhbHx8MHx8fA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080" />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.nav {
  min-height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #979797;
}

.link {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #3e433e;
  line-height: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #navbar-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 57px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 0 !important;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-out !important;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-out !important;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #navbar-menu.show {
    height: calc(100vh - 57px) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! It's definetely a good solution, the only problem was that it broke some margins of the items in the menu. Maybe by something I didn't explicity share in the question. But anyway, thanks again!